# JQuery $.post function(data)

Tags: jquery, function, .post

My code looks like this at the moment:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var id = ($(this).val());

    $.post('ajax.php', {id: id}, function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

ajax.php

```
<?php echo 'HELLO!'; ?>
```

But it doesn't work. I'm really stuck right now. Can you see any errors in the `$.post`? I'm 99% sure something is wrong there.

Comment: Do this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/5gYf3/**, and tell us what the console says.

Comment: this code works fine because of this -1

Comment: @adeneo, I prefer `console.log(arguments);` `1.`only one row, `2.`not need to declare/know arguments number...

Comment: @vp_arth - I tend to use both, depends on what I'm doing, but in this case using arguments would be easier, but I just typed that really fast to try an get the error message etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would check the request url to see if the page is found wich one your are calling.
There are situations that the url you are using is not correct/not found.

My prefered way is to check with Chrome Dev Tools.

[image: Network tab Chrome Dev Tools]